# What are the Ribbon UI libraries on MAC?

Tags: macos, ribbon

As the title suggested, i'm investigating possibility to develop a MAC app with Ribbon UI. But the only Ribbon UI library i can find is QtitanRibbon which is for QT. Are there any others out there?

Comment: Can you confirm that you are talking about the QT... the C++ framework developed by Qt Development Frameworks at Nokia. http://www.qtcentre.org/content/

Comment: Yes, I'm talking about QT developed by Nokia. I believe they sold it out now.